# Why don't people deep clone in C# by using a JObject one-liner?

Tags: c#

I was recently looking over this question on deep cloning in C#: [How do you do a deep copy of an object in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-net)

I'm not a C#/.NET expert, so if this is completely off, someone please correct me. Why aren't people suggesting doing the following?

```
JObject.FromObject(theObject).DeepClone().ToObject<TheObjectClass>();
```

The most upvoted answers are extremely verbose solutions and I'm sure it's for a good reason, so I really want to understand why this one-liner isn't valid.

Comment: What if an object can't be represented in JSON format?

Comment: @DStanley thank you, so this at least would work with all objects that can be represented in a JSON format?

Comment: Probably - but it also has the potential side-effect of having multiple copies of objects that have multiple references to them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But why aren't people suggesting doing the following?
>
> ```
> JObject.FromObject(theObject).DeepClone().ToObject<TheObjectClass>();
> ```

Because not every object can be serialized to JSON. Specifically objects with circular references, or objects where you have multiple references to the same instance.